# Get an element from a associative array in bash with set -u

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I am using

- `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release-(x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

---

I am using a **asscoiative array** to store values and I want to check, whether a **key is contained within the array** with **`set -u`** included in the bash file.

The important part (you can find the script below) is where I want to get the value from the array like this `${backups[$service]}`

**What is not working:**

- When I execute the script with `set -u` it just exits with an error state and says `line xx: backups[$service]: unbound variable`.
- It also does not work for `${instances[$1]}`.

**What is working though:**

- Without `set -u` it works.
- `${!backups[*]}` works with `set -u`
- `${backups[@]}` works with `set -u`

---

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

# all the services
services=(
  "service_without_backup"
  "service_that_needs_backup"
)

my_service="service_that_needs_backup"

# all the services that need a backup
declare -A backups
for service in $my_service
do
  backups[$service]=1
done

...
some other code
... 

# loop over all the services    
for service in ${services[@]}
do

  ...
  do something common to all services
  ...

  # backup services when defined to
  if [ ${backups[$service]} ]; then
    echo "    copy backup file"        
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could test using [bash's parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to return a particular value if the given value doesn't exist:

```
if [ "${backups[$service]:-NOT_HERE}" != "NOT_HERE" ]; then
    # do what you want if the value does exist in the array
fi
```

Comment: Really nice, it works as expected. I didn't look into that direction Thank you.

Comment: It works now, must've misspelled something. I'm going to delete previous comments for sake of brevity. TL;DR `$ set -u; declare -A my_array; key=missing; my_array[exists]=value ; [[ -n "${my_array[$key]-}" ]] || echo Unset` results in output `Unset` on 4.1, 4.2 and 4.3